# How to check if a string contains a word longer than 50 characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if a string contains a word longer than 50 characters?

Comment: There are tons of ways to do this... do you need fast?  Or just easy?

Comment: I agree with Nix...lots of ways to do this.  Which makes me ask what version of .Net are you using.

Answer (score 7):

Eg. with LINQ:

```
string toCheck = "your string here";
bool isLong = toCheck
    .Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Any(s => s.Length > 50);
```

---

**Edit**

Out of curiosity, with people suspecting Regex would be much faster (I assumed so too), I've run few simple tests. Have to admit I'm surprised with results:

*LINQ (or precisely, string.Split and LINQ) seems to perform over 3-20 times faster than compiled Regex and 6-30 than uncompiled one.*

I've run `1'000'000` iterations of each solution under `Release` mode, checking 4 sample strings:

- one with none 50-chars+ long words
- one with exactly one 50-chars+ long word, at the **end** of the string
- one with exactly one 50-chars+ long word, at the **begining** of the string
- one with multiple 50-chars+ long words, spread around the string

Results can be seen here (LINQ vs compiled regex):

> LINQ [noLongWords], 1000000 iterations. Result = False: 867 ms
>
> LINQ [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 986 ms
>
> LINQ [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 827 ms
>
> LINQ [manyLongWordsEverywhere], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 2399 ms
>
> Regex [noLongWords], 1000000 iterations. Result = False: 16714 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 14225 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 6483 ms
>
> Regex [manyLongWordsEverywhere], 1000000 iterations. Result = True: 6675 ms

Source code for tests is available [here](http://pastebin.com/DfMEC9C4).

Of course, under regular conditions (who sane runs `1'000'000` iterations?), difference is irrelevant and one should go for easier/more maintainable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your experiment. I have added some response in my answer

Answer (score 5):

The obligatory Regex answer:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\w){50,}");
re.IsMatch(input);
```

PS: While I tend to stay away from Regex, I feel in this case a Regex is simpler and faster.

**Edit after @jimmy_keen's experiment**

@jimmy_keen - Thanks for that.

I removed the group, since it was not really needed and the time taken was much lesser for Regex, below is the output for compiled:

Changed Regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w{50,}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Output:

> LINQ [noLongWords], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = False: 725 ms
>
> LINQ [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 760 ms
>
> LINQ [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 651 ms
>
> LINQ [manyLongWordsEverywhere],
>   1000000 iterations. Result = True:
>   2107 ms
>
> Regex [noLongWords], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = False: 2773 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 7217 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 3279 ms
>
> Regex [manyLongWordsEverywhere],
>   1000000 iterations. Result = True:
>   3283 ms
>
> DONE

The regex being slower than LINQ in this situation was sort of surprising for, but maybe not, because I have been burnt by regexes many times. They are a great tool, but very heavy. In this case, I was thinking the regex would be able to come slightly ahead of LINQ, but that is not to be.

A slightly more complex, but similar regex outperforms LINQ in many long words case:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9]{50,}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

> LINQ [noLongWords], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = False: 611 ms
>
> LINQ [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 642 ms
>
> LINQ
>   [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 549 ms
>
> LINQ
>   [manyLongWordsEverywhere], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 1914 ms
>
> Regex [noLongWords], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = False: 2085 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtEnd], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 4147 ms
>
> Regex [oneLongWordAtBegining], 1000000
>   iterations. Result = True: 1569 ms
>
> Regex [manyLongWordsEverywhere],
>   1000000 iterations. Result = True:
>   1580 ms
>
> DONE

**But I still believe that the simplicty of the regex and that the performance difference starts to be seen at 100,000 iterations or more, regex is still the best solution here**

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what punctuation you want to look for but basically:

```
string input = "fox jumped over the fence.";
bool hasLongWord = input.Split(new[] { ' ', ';', '.' }, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Any(word => word.Length > 50);
```

Comment: Wouldn't a regex be much faster?

Answer (score 0):

Errr...I don't think you'll find anything faster than:

```
private static Regex rxLongWord = new Regex( @"\w{50,}" ) ;
public HasLongWord( string s )
{
  bool foundLongWord = rxLongWord.IsMatch( s ) ;
  return foundLongWord ;
}
```

Comment: It works for me just need to change to check if url or email in string longer than 130 characters

Comment: Of course, you might first want to settle on a definition of "word" B^) &mdash; it is, how do you say, subject to interpretation.