# How to find out if some word in a string is bigger than 50 Characters in PHP?

Tags: php

How to do such thing in PHP? I have fond on this forum only solution for C# [How to check if a string contains a word longer than 50 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760070/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-word-longer-than-50-characters)

E.g. I have a string:

```
$string_to_check = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa rrrr fe we we hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhererererereerdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfttttfsd hhghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh fd s hoefjsd k
bla bla bla";
```

And I want to make an if condition so when string contains a word that is 50 or more characters long return false; else return true;

Any advice how to solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this function:

```
function not_long_word($sentence, $length = 50) {
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
      if (strlen($value) > $length) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

usage:

```
$text = "word wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooord";
if (not_long_word($text)) {
    echo "there no word longer than 50!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "a word in-this-string-contains-fifty-or-more-ch ";

if(preg_match('/\S{50,}/',$str)) 
{ 
   echo 'String contains a word of more than 50 characters'; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo 'String does not contains a word of more than 50 characters'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
if(strlen($string_to_check) < 50 )
{
 ...
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: OP wants to check individual words, not the full sentence.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, split it into its individual words (assuming that space is the separator), and then find out whether any word is longer than 50 characters:

```
$array = explode(" ",$string);
foreach ($array as $word) { 
  if (strlen($word) > 50) {
    echo "{$word}\n"
  }
}
```

If the separator may have multiple spaces/tabs, then you might choose a regular expression:

```
$array = preg_split('[\t\s]+', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested this out and it works well.

```
check_word_length( $string_to_check );

function check_word_length( $string_to_check ){
    foreach ( explode(' ', $string_to_check )  as $word) {
        if ( strlen($word) > 50 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```